# Reading multiple fields on one table and joining them single line records from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables A and B. A has unique records while B may have several references to one record in A.

A table -> A.UserID,A.Image1.ID,A.Image2.ID,A.UserName

B table -> B.ImageID,B.ImageURL,ImageDescription

B. Image ID is unique and could have at least two records correspond to Image!ID and Image2ID in table A.

In my query, need to read A.UserName,B.Image1URL and B.Image2URL.

Following SQL query is to read one image. How I could modify this to read both Image1 and Image2 in one SQL query ?.

```
@"SELECT A.*,B.* FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON B.Image1ID = A.Image1ID
WHERE A.UserID = @Parameter1;";
```

So in the result, I need following :

UserID 
Image1URL
Image2URL

What's the best way to get this done in mySQL ?

Comment: Add another `JOIN` to `Image2ID`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I tried this but I missed putting 'AS' which gave a duplicate error. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join same table twice -

```
SELECT A.UserID, A.UserName, img1.ImageURL, img2.ImageURL
  FROM A
 INNER JOIN B as img1
    ON img1.ImageID = A.Image1ID
 INNER JOIN B as img2
    ON img2.ImageID = A.Image2ID
 WHERE A.UserID = @Parameter1;
```